# jquery popup on page load that wont be indexed by spiders

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm nearing completion of a website redesign and im looking for a solution to notify regular visitors to the site to refresh the page to update the site as it will still show the old design (we are using browser leverage cache). I had a simple php script that displays a message box at the top of the page, but the contents were indexed by the search engines and effected listings. From what I have read so far, you cannot hide text from the search engines, if its their, they will include it in their crawl?

I could do a simple image, but thats not ideal.

Does anyone know of a jquery popup on first page load that can display a message and wont get indexed? Something very simple and light that wont put visitors off. Sorry of this has been asked before or there are readily solutions available, I couldn't find any, may be I'm asking the wrong question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work - create a new page for the message and the following in the `<head>`:

```
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX">
```

and load it in an `iframe` in a lightbox.

[using-robots-meta-tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2007/03/using-robots-meta-tag.html)

Comment: I think this solution will work best for the time being, the search engines will obey the NOINDEX rule. Dont know why I didnt come up with this already, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try encoding it with base64, and then decode on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine once told me that AJAX content is not crawlable but on the contrary major Search Engines have specific crawling mechanism to crawl AJAX Content.
([AJAX Crawling by Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started)

As Marcus Johansson suggested I would suggest to base64 encode your document or in my opinion you could try the following.

The message at the top could utilize and iframe (I hate these personally) and the document within will contain the [nofollow and noindex meta tags](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93710). These will Block Crawling access to your document containing these tags.

Another unrecommended solution (like the images one) is to use Flash, but mentioning Flash I must tell you that some major search engines are working on [crawling within Flash content](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2008/06/google-learns-to-crawl-flash.html), too.

Let me know how you will solve your problem :)

Have a great day!